# How to create new rows for each month within a date range?

Tags: sql-server, date, calendar, range, record

I need to create a view that creates new rows for each month between a date range.
A sample of the data for my booking table is shown below.

```
Booking ID  Booking Name   Start Date  End Date    Booked Days
1           HolidayUSA     1/01/2020   15/02/2020  46
2           HolidayEurope  20/01/2020  10/03/2020  50
3           HolidayUK      14/03/2020  19/03/2020  5
```

I want to create a view that will add a new record for each month between the date range, calculate the number of booked days based off the days for that month, and add month/year fields.

**Expected output:**

[image: Expected output table]

I’m using Microsoft SQL Server.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend to use a Stored procedure instead of view, as you cannot use insert in a view and stored procedure will provide you much better control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tally or numbers table based approach.  The tally CTE create a sequence (up to 12^4 or 20,736 days (which could be increased to whatever is necessary)) to extend the calendar by days.  Then it aggregates by months.

```
;with
n(n) as (select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) v(n)),
tally_cte(N) as (
     select row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
     from n n1 cross join n n2 cross join n n3 cross join n n4)
select booking_id, booking_name, start_dt, end_dt, dfp.dfp,
       year(dt.booking_dt) [Year], convert(char(3), dt.booking_dt, 0) [Month],
       count(*) booked_days
from #test t
     cross apply
     (select dateadd(d, n-1, t.start_dt) booking_dt 
      from tally_cte
      where n<=datediff(d, t.start_dt, t.end_dt)) dt
     cross apply
     (select datefromparts(year(dt.booking_dt), month(dt.booking_dt), 1) dfp) dfp
group by booking_id, booking_name, start_dt, end_dt, dfp.dfp,
       year(dt.booking_dt), convert(char(3), dt.booking_dt, 0)
order by 1, 3, 5;
```

Output

```
booking_id          booking_name    start_dt    end_dt  dfp Year    Month   booked_days
1   HolidayUSA      2020-01-01      2020-02-15  2020-01-01  2020    Jan     31
1   HolidayUSA      2020-01-01      2020-02-15  2020-02-01  2020    Feb     14
2   HolidayEurope   2020-01-20      2020-03-10  2020-01-01  2020    Jan     12
2   HolidayEurope   2020-01-20      2020-03-10  2020-02-01  2020    Feb     29
2   HolidayEurope   2020-01-20      2020-03-10  2020-03-01  2020    Mar     9
3   HolidayUK       2020-03-14      2020-03-19  2020-03-01  2020    Mar     5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked amazingly! Really appreciate your time and efforts. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

This is my closest approximation:

```
declare @tb table  ([Booking Id] int, [Booking Name] varchar(30),
                    [Start Date] datetime, [End Date] datetime)
-- Sample data
insert @tb values
    (1, 'HolidayUSA','20200101','20200215'),
    (2, 'HolidayEUROPE','20200120','20200310'),
    (3, 'HolidayUK','20200314','20200319')

-- Showing sample data
select *, dateDiff(dd, [Start Date], [End Date]) [Booked Days]
from @tb

declare @dd smallint
select @dd = max(dateDiff(dd, [Start Date], [End Date])) from @tb

with day_cte as (
    select 1 as nbd union all
    select nbd + 1 from day_cte where nbd <= @dd)
select [Booking Id], [Booking Name], [Start Date], [End Date]
    , datePart(yy, dateAdd(dd, nbd, [Start Date])) [Year]
    , left(dateName(mm, dateAdd(dd, nbd, [Start Date])), 3) [Month]
    , count(*) [Booked Days]
from @tb, day_cte
where nbd <= dateDiff(dd, [Start Date], [End Date])
group by [Booking Id], [Booking Name], [Start Date], [End Date]
    , datePart(yy, dateAdd(dd, nbd, [Start Date]))
    , dateName(mm, dateAdd(dd, nbd, [Start Date]))
```